# How can colour streaking from scanner be eliminated using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, image-editing

[image: CoverScan]

Here is a scan of an album cover. The scanner creates bands of colour streaking at regular intervals horizontally across the image.

Is it possible to eliminate these artifacts using Photoshop, so that the colour of the card stock is even, all without affecting the textures? Use of the clone tool, patch tool, etc are not permissible.

Edit: The colour streaking is likely a hardware issue, as I have cleaned every inch of the glass multiple times (both sides), and cleaned the calibration target as well. I can't replace the scanner anytime soon.

Edit: Upon further investigation, I've noticed that this phenomenon hasn't occurred on every album cover that I have scanned. I scanned the other three sleeves from this album, one bright orange, one yellow, and one green. Curiously, the banding only occurs on the pink and the orange sleeves. I tried scanning them in grayscale, but banding still resulted.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why is the use of the clone tool or patch tool not permissible?  What have you tried? What has failed?

Comment: Also why not mask black and use solid colors?

Comment: I would scan to get the black... *eliminating* the pink.. then add a solid pink once I have a good scan of the black.

Comment: Just for principle's sake. The scan must be as accurate to the physical media as possible.

Comment: Get a better scanner perhaps?  I don't really see what else  you can do here since you've already ruled out the use of the tools in Photoshop which could be used to fix it, and now you appear to be ruling out Scott's suggestion to use a different approach.

Comment: I see, I was hoping for something along the lines of how a Fast Fourier Transform can be used to eliminate moiré from halftone image scans. I tried using frequency separation, but it still affects the texture too much.

Comment: You have 2 conflicting targets you want to preserve the scan and eliminate the halftones.  Which is it? Which do you want to do have as much of a reproducible artwork or preserve as much out of the scan as possible. If later then you need a higher quality scan.

Comment: By the way if you did masking way you'd get this in a minute: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JzBF.png ive added the texture back a little, you can offcourse add as miuch as you want. Results would be superior if i didn't have a very compressed low res jpeg to work with.

Comment: I wanted to preserve the texture, and equalize the colour. There is no halftone present on the sleeve; it's pink card stock with laser-printed text. Scott did mention masking as a solution earlier, and I found a way to make it work with other scanned sleeves (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is there are *real world* limitations in play that you may be unaware of. It's not as simple as "tweaking" a setting anywhere. Because of these limitations, it **is** going to most likely take more work than simply scanning and being done.

What you *see* as a solid pink.. is most likely **not** actually a solid pink. Printed items are created with a combination of cyan, magenta, yellow, and black *dots* [like this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/156080/creating-cmyk-halftone-dot-patterns-manually-in-illustrator/156082#156082):

> [image]
> <sub>https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/abstract-artistic-halftone-pattern-illustration-gm1026102792-275201376?phrase=cmyk+dots</sub>

The human eye then "blends" the dots to create an appearance of a solid color. You can use a loupe or magnifying glass on printed materials to see the actual dots.

*Rarely* is what looks like a solid color *actually* solid. It is possible to print a solid color via [spot colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_color), but I think it's unlikely *that* album cover uses any spot colors (it would probably be cost prohibitive for a record label - cuz they generally want profits for themselves).

So, the scanner *sees* these dot patterns and creates what's called a [**moiré**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) when scanning. This is what you are seeing as "streaks." There's little that can be done about a scanner's moiré - it is simply the result of scanning something that has been commercially printed. Moirés are most noticeable in fields of similar/solid colors.

Sometimes scanning at a **45° angle** can help reduce any scanner moiré, but it may *never* vanish entirely.

The *real solution* is to scan for the black. Get a solid black scan eliminating the pink. Then, in image editing software add a solid pink background to match the original cover. And finally a "pattern overlay" to create the pseudo texture. At least, that's how I would handle a similar project.

Comment: It is hard to see on that image, but this particular sleeve is pink card stock and it looks like the text was laser printed, so there's no halftone present.

I am not sure what you mean when you say "scan for black" and "eliminating the pink".

Comment: That "texture" could very well be a stock texture. In which case.. well.. all you can do is try and mimic it the nest you can. Get a quality scan of a small portion and create a seamless pattern tile from that. Either way.. I think separating the black from the pink is the best bet.

Comment: So the banding only occurs on the pink and orange sleeves. What I will have to do is scan the banded sleeves and the yellow sleeve in grayscale, do a C-A Fill on the text of the yellow sleeve, isolate the text from the pink/orange sleeve, as you mentioned, then transpose that onto the filled sleeve. Then after all of that, I can use a blending mode to change the colour back to pink/orange.

Answer (score 1):

Just that black text on the pink looks like it can be recreated easily with a proper font. It's like something simple typewriter art. Try it. Then insert the background you like.

A monospace font should be used. Courier New is quite close, but not exact. Here's the scanned letter D and a retyped version of it in Illustrator.

[image]

A slight stroke is added to make the glyphs look heavy enough

Comment: I have actually done this on many occasions, but it is very tedious. Identifying the fonts, and then mapping the vectors onto the image with tracking and kerning is incredibly time-consuming, and a last resort.

Comment: Just this case is a simple one. I added an example.

Comment: I did give you upvotes because it is a possible solution, but because I wish to preserve the texture of the media, it's not a solution that I can use here.